# widely accepted as the heir apparent of -- what does "the heir apparent of" mean?

Tags: meaning

> HTML5 (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) is the fifth major revision of the W3C’s HTML, the markup language for publishing on the World Wide Web. It has been in draft for several years and changes regularly, but it is widely accepted as the **heir apparent of** HTML 4.01 and XHTML.

I don't understand **"the apparent of"** part.

Comment: As you'll see from @Anda's link, ***apparent*** there contrasts with *heir **presumptive*** (someone currently first in line of succession who *can* be displaced by the birth of another person). It's a fossilised usage (with non-standard word order) defined by OED as *In **heir apparent** (and its imitations): **Manifest, evident, obvious**; applied to one who will undoubtedly inherit, if he survive the present possessor, as opposed to an **heir presumptive**, who though at present the nearest in succession, is liable to have his hope intercepted by the birth of a nearer heir.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heir_apparent),

> An **heir apparent** is a person, male or female, who is first in line of succession and cannot be displaced from inheriting by the birth of another person.

So in this context it's used figuratively to explain that HTML 5 is the successor of HTML 4.01 and XHTML.